# xelatex mysteriously exiting with code 1

Tags: xetex

I have a wrapper round `xelatex` to tidy up all the garbage that's generated.  Basically, my workflow is: write a letter in tex -> review and print in pdf.

I currently do this with the following:

```
$ cat ~/bin/texp
#!/bin/sh

# tex to pdf without garbage side-effect files lying around.

set -ex

dir=`mktemp -d ./XXXXXXXX`

#mkdir $dir

for i; do :; done
# echo "Last arg : $i"

cp $i $dir
#pushd $dir
cd $dir
xelatex -interaction=batchmode "$@"
#popd
cd ..

mv -v $dir/*.pdf .
rm -r $dir
```

but for my latest letter, I (and the wrapper) sees an exit code of 1, and so the garbage is left lying around.  The only terminal output of xelatex is:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

That doesn't help me diagnose what the problem might be.  The PDF looks fine.

Is `restricted \write18 enabled` or `entering extended mode` an error?  How do I find out what the error is?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please also show a MWE of the TeX file?

Comment: The restricted write18 and extended mode messages are normal. there is no _terminal_ output as you have suppressed it with `-interaction=batchmode` (that's all that does) so you need to look in the `.log` file for any error messages.